# Creating procedure SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to SQL, and I'm trying to learn it. I'm creating a procedure to INSERT Members into Member table.

Im using this (which ofc works):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMember
AS
INSERT INTO Member (FirstName, LastName, City)
VALUES ('Blla', 'Blla', 'Blla')
```

But... I want to know if it is possible to create a procedure which when I execute it, to ask user for input. For example: When I execute the procedure it should go like this:

```
@FirstName = 'SOME FIRSTNAME'
@LastName = 'SOME LASTNAME'
@City = 'SOME CITY'
```

I didn't try anything yet, because I don't know if that is possible. Help please ? Any reference ?

Comment: If you like an answer, accept it

Answer (score 5):

Try this, change your stored procedure to accept parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMember
   (@FirstName varchar(50), @LastName varchar(50), @City varchar(50)) 
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Member (FirstName, LastName, City)
   VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @City)
END
```

Now you can call this SP in SQL Management Studio

```
exec InsertMember 'Blla','Blla','Blla'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter the procedure:

```
ALTER PROC SP_GETCUSTOMER 
(@CUSTOMERID NCHAR,@CITY NVARCHAR(50),
@COUNTRY NVARCHAR(50))
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT ContactName,CompanyName FROM DimCustomers
END
```

Comment: this is alter the procedure